# Mysql command line showing access denied for @'172.X' when using --password but not when interactive

Tags: mysql, sql

Not sure why this is happening.

My user has the right password/privileges (where host is '%')

If I run the command as such:

mysql -h myhost -u myuser -p

Password:

It connects.

However if I do:

mysql -h myhost -u myuser --password=

I get Access Denied for user 'myuser'@'172.xxx' <-- internal IP

Not sure why this is happening and I can't seem to figure out how to resolve it. Adding it the host for 172.% doesn't seem to work either.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the password contains a leading space?. There should be no space between the password and `-p` option.

Comment: @Sal If his password had a leading space, he would have to put it into quotes (assuming Linux / bash).

Comment: No space. Also did try wrapping in quotes. This is on Amazon RDS btw.

Comment: Out of curiosity, did my answer (especially my EDIT 1) help you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

From `man mysql` (emphasis mine):

> SYNOPSIS
>    mysql [options] db_name
>
> --password[=password], -p[password]
> The password to use when connecting to the server. **If you use the short option form (-p), you cannot have a space between the option and the password.** If you omit the password value following the --password or -p option on the command line, mysql prompts for one. [...]

Let's concentrate on the first command you mentioned:

```
mysql -h myhost -u myuser -p Password
```

You said that this works, but in fact, it shouldn't. According to the manual, there must be no space between `-p` and the password. If there is one (as in your case), Password will just be interpreted as additional command line parameter (in this case: the last command line parameter).

On the other hand, according to the manual, the last command line parameter is the name of the database to use.

Thus, according to my understanding of the manual, the following *should* happen when the command shown above is entered:

The MySQL client should connect to `myhost` and then (on the command line) ask for the password for `myuser` (because `-p` is given *without* the actual password from its point of view). If the password is entered correctly, it should login `myuser` and switch immediately to the database which has Password (i.e. the last command line parameter) as its name.

If it connects immediately without prompting for `myuser`'s password (as you wrote), then there probably is no password for `myuser` yet.

In every case, after the actual login is done, you should get an error message because there probably is no database which has Password (i.e. the last command line parameter) as its name. Could you please tell us if you get such an error message after login, and if there is a database which has Password (i.e. the last command line parameter) as its name?

If we know the reason why the command shown above works although it shouldn't, then we will know the reason why your second command (`mysql -h myhost -u myuser --password=`) fails.

**EDIT 1** (after you have edited your question)

This behavior is expected. Saying `--password=` is formally the same as saying `--password=''`; in other words, you are telling the MySQL client that it should use the empty string as password.

If you want it to prompt for the password, then just use `--password` (without the equal sign) instead. Your command line line then would be:

```
mysql -h myhost -u myuser --password
```

Comment: I edited the post. There was a formatting issue causing confusion. In the first example, I am not typing in the password with a space--I was trying to articulate the Password Prompt.

Comment: See EDIT 1 in my answer.